# i want to get data and show it in a modal by click on details button .how can i do that in this code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a search form. after click on search button I have this table that shows the result. I use a viewmodel to fill this table.

```
   @if (Model.productsDtos != null)
                                {
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered zero-configuration dataTable" role="grid">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <th>count</th>
                                                <th></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            @foreach (var item in Model.productsDtos)
                                            {
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
                                                    <td>@item.inventory</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                       <a href="javascript:void()" onclick="GetDetails('@item.ProductId')">Details</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            }
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                }
```

javascript func:

```
 function GetDetails(id) {
        var postData = {
            'ProductId': id,
        };
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET",
            url: "Details",
            data: postData,
            success: function (data) { }

        });
    }
```

action in controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Details(SellerProductsViewModel model,string ProductId)
        {
            model.productDetailsDtos= _service.GetDetails(ProductId);
            return View(model);
        }
```

by click on details button , table doesnt show any data. in fact table not render anymore.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're expecting to happen after making the AJAX request.  The `success` function explicitly does nothing: `function (data) { }`  Did you mean to do something with the result returned by the server?

Comment: Ajax only send the parameter to action 'Details' . I want to show the action result in that table.

Comment: Then you'd have to write the functionality to do exactly that.  If the `Details` action is returning a view, then presumably the `data` variable in the `success` function contains HTML, correct?  You can use your browser's debugging tools to confirm what's being received in the AJAX response.  (And you may be getting an error, because you're telling the AJAX operation to expect `'json'` data.)  If you want to insert that HTML into the page, you'd use jQuery code in that `success` function to do that.  For example: `$('#someElementID').html(data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show details by modal in your question, So i use `bootstrap modal` to write a simple demo here, I hope it is what you expect.

****Model****

```
  public class Test
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string ClassName { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
//For testing convenience, I just hard code here.

 List<Test> test = new List<Test>()
    {
        new Test()
        {
            Id = "1",
            Name = "JACK",
            Age = 23,
            ClassName = "ClassA",
            Country = "USA"
        },
        new Test()
        {
            Id = "2",
            Name = "NACY",
            Age = 22,
            ClassName = "ClassB",
            Country = "CHINA"
        },
        new Test()
        {
            Id = "3",
            Name = "LILY",
            Age = 27,
            ClassName = "Classc",
            Country = "UK"
        },

    };


   //I use this page to show the table

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View(test);
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Details(string ProductId)
    {

       //I select the details by Id,It is the same function as _service.GetDetails(ProductId); in your code

        var result = test.Where(x => x.Id == ProductId).FirstOrDefault();

       // I return the details as the type of json

        return Json(result);
    }
```

**view**

```
@model List<Modal.Models.Test>

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>


<table class="table table-striped table-bordered zero-configuration dataTable" role="grid">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>count</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
            <td>@item.Age</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#staticBackdrop" data-bs-toggle="modal" onclick="GetDetails('@item.Id') ">Details</a>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>


@* This is the modal component, you can find the  same code on the bootstrap  website *@

<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Details</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="Test">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




@section Scripts
{
    <script>
    function GetDetails(id) {       
        
        var postData = {
                    'ProductId': id,
                };
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',            
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/details",
                data: postData,              
                success: function (res) { 
                    console.log(res)
                    document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML = '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered zero-configuration dataTable" role="grid">'
                                                                 +'<thead><tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>ClassName</th><th>Country</th></tr></thead>'                                                                
                                                                 +'<tbody><tr><td>'+res["id"]+'</td><td>'+res["name"]+'</td><td>'+res["age"]+'</td><td>'+res["className"]+'</td><td>'+res["country"]+'</td></tr></tbody>'
                                                                 +'</table>';

                  
                  $('#staticBackdrop').modal()
                },
                

            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

**Show results**

[image]